# Exception handler does not work in closures?

Tags: php, exception

I've trying to use this:

```
$error_handler = function($severity, $message, $filename, $lineno) {
    throw new ErrorException($message, 0, $severity, $filename, $lineno);
};

$exception_handler = function($exception) {
    self::invokeHttpError(500);
};

set_error_handler($error_handler, E_ALL | E_STRICT);
set_exception_handler($exception_handler);
```

However, it fails when I call this:

```
$fn = function() {
    $application->test(); // $application is undefined
};
$fn();
```

The error handler is called, but not the exception handler. What is happening?

Comment: How do you know that nothing was invoked?

Comment: The default exception handler is called.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dereferencing an undefined object results in a *fatal and uncatchable* error. That's why your exception handler and error handler are not called when this happens.

This behaviour really irritates me as a developer though, I wish it would get turned into a catchable exception instead.

**Update**

One thing you could do to curb this problem is to throw an ErrorException inside your regular error handler. This would prevent an uncatchable fatal error when dereferencing an undefined symbol.

Comment: You're right, even outside of the closure problem occurs. This is terrible.

Comment: I hear ya :) this always forces me to read my server logs as well as my application logs to find out if a live system experiences any issues. This is also referred to as the white screen of death btw. Really annoying.